# How to sort LinkedList<String>?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparable

I need to sort the Strings of a LinkedList by the length of the Strings, but would like to keep the order of same-length strings (not sorted lexicographically).

Sample input:

```
this
is
just
a
test
```

Sample Output:

```
a
is
this
just
test
```

I am trying to do this with a `Comparable<LinkedList<String>>` and a `compareTo` method, but I don't get the correct output (mine still sorts it lexicographically)

```
public class Q3_sorting implements Comparable<LinkedList<String>> {
    Scanner keyboardScanner = null;
    LinkedList<String> fileList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

// [...] some code here

```
public int compareTo(LinkedList<String> o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        o = fileList;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size() -1; i++) {
            if (fileList.get(i).length() == o.get(i+1).length()) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (fileList.get(i).length() > o.get(i+1).length()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (fileList.get(i).length() < o.get(i+1).length()) {
                return 1;
            }

        }
```

I then use
`Q3_sorting sort = new Q3_sorting(args);`
`Collections.sort(sort.fileList);`
in my main method. I then print the list out...

but I get this as output:

```
a
is
just
test
this
```

How would I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting strings, not lists of strings. To do this, you need to define a `Comparator<String>` to compare two strings by their length as follows:

```
public class ByLength implements Comparator<String> {
  @Override
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
    return a.length() - b.length();
  }
}
```

Then, to sort the list, you need to call:

```
Collections.sort(sort.fileList, new ByLength());
```

Also note that sorting a `LinkedList` is very inefficient and you should use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Any reasonable implementation of `Collections.sort` will copy the data out to an array before sorting, and then copy back in. However, `LinkedList` is generally inefficient and should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

You should create a comparator:

```
public class Q3_sorting implements Comparator<String> {
public int compare(String a, String b) {
 return a.length() - b.length();
}
```

And then sort it with the method:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Q3_sorting());
```

Note that what you want to do is sort the Strings inside the List. By implementing a comparator of List (or a comparable, as it works on the same purpose here) what you are telling the JVM is that you want to compare different List's.

You could also achieve your objective by implementing a Comparable in the class to sort, but you can't as long as String is final so you cannot extend. Therefore there is no other way than to implement a Comparator, which is simpler too :)

Comment: The `Comparator` can also be used oustide of just sorting `List` implementations, such as for `TreeSet` and `TreeMap`.

Comment: Yes. It can also be used to sort arrays too, through the Arrays utility class, among custom uses.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` overload. You need a `Comparator<String>` not a `Comparator<LinkedList<String>>`. Note that the javadoc of Collections.sort guarantees a stable sort (keep the order of equal strings, equal mean equal according you comparator).

Answer (score -1):

Strings unfortunately don't have a property that signifies what position they hold in a linked list.  You will therefore need to create a custom data object that does keep track of that information.  Either that or write your own custom sort method for the linked list and call that instead of Collections.sort().